# Why was this question written in Japanese automatically flagged as low-quality?

Tags: support

This question, written in Japanese, has been automatically flagged as low-quality:

[最終講義・懇親会の出欠連絡の葉書に、伝統的にどんなコメントを書くべきですか。](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21854/%E6%9C%80%E7%B5%82%E8%AC%9B%E7%BE%A9%E3%81%A8%E6%87%87%E8%A6%AA%E4%BC%9A%E3%81%AE%E5%A0%B4%E5%90%88-%E4%BC%9D%E7%B5%B1%E7%9A%84%E3%81%AB%E8%91%89%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A9%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B3%E3%83%A1%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%82%92%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F%E6%96%B9%E3%81%8C%E3%81%84%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B)

Perhaps it's because its length in characters is shorter than it would be in English.  Perhaps it's because it contains no Latin characters.  I can't tell, but I don't think this question would have been flagged if it were written in English.  If it's a matter of length, perhaps the code needs to be changed―an equivalent post in Japanese will usually have fewer characters than in English.

Why was this post flagged as low-quality?

Comment: related: http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/71